# JMSTimestamp is showing greater time than the current time for few transactions

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I am capturing the difference between the time JMSlistener has picked the message and JMSTimestamp(which the producer has sent). When I calculate the different between these two values. The result is negative value. I was wondering how can be JMSTimestamp i.e set by the producer is greater than the consumer picked time.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is the listener code I have return

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            log.info("====Time taken by Listener to read::==="
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - message
                            .getJMSTimestamp()) + " ms"); // I am getting negative value here

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Error while reading the message", e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the system clocks on the sender/receiver machines are not synchronized.

You can't rely on these timestamps unless you keep the clocks reasonably sync'd (e.g. `ntpd`).

Comment: Thank you very much Gary. But only few transactions are getting greater timestamp value.

Comment: That will likely be the case, even if the clocks are only a few milliseconds apart. If, say, the sender clock is 30ms ahead of the receiver clock and it only takes 20ms to transit the broker, it will appear the message arrived 10ms before it was sent. If it's linux, you can compare the times with `date +%s%3N` to get the time in milliseconds since the epoch.